# Car sfx library

Tags: sfx

I have a small animation project with a quick turnaround which needs some car sounds for a modern hatchback (SEAT).

I wondered if anyone had any good suggestions for libraries that might cover this project with a good range of sounds for this type of vehicle? The sounds needed would be mostly external car sounds and I need them to be pretty close and as clean as possible as this a very dry, pristine animated environment, so too much ambience won't quite cut it.

I've had a listen to the BOOM everyday cars library which seems very good for internal sounds but isn't quite right for the exterior as there is too much distance/ambience on the recordings.

Any help much appreciated!

Cheers,
S

Answer (score 2):

If Boom didnt give you what you needed, you could always record the sounds yourself if you have the ability to. Ive had some issues with designing car shots myself in the past and I have just done some creative design work and it has worked for me. I have had to rely on creatively using the libraries I have to design what was needed, this involving "Everyday Cars" and others from Sound Ideas and Hollywood Edge, but my big thing about libraries is that they never have "Exactly what you want when it comes to realistic sounds such as cars and what not.

If anything, I would try to find the car you need and record the audio yourself, then you have exactly what you want. If not, do some designing and create some audio magic. Fool the listener, that is the best thing about sound design...only you know.

Hope this helped. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Tony, I don't have much time to go out and record the sounds myself so looks like I'll just have to work with what I've got!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend auditioning some of the car sounds on our individual downloads site. Soundrangers has a lot of good car sounds!

[Pro Sound Effects Individual Downloads](http://download.prosoundeffects.com/#!explorer?s=compact%20car&o=relevance&d=a&show=30&pg=1)

I like Everyday Cars from Boom as well. Tony is right though, it's rare that you find EXACTLY what you need from a library. But you can usually manipulate or layer sounds to get the job done if you don't have time to go out and record exactly what you need.

Good luck!

Best,
David Forshee
[Pro Sound Effects](http://www.prosoundeffects.com)

Comment: Hi David, I'll check out the link and see if there's anything useful! 

Thanks